# Fix: InvalidAlgorithmError: The specified alg value is not allowed while trying to decode encoded jwt token in Python

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, pyjwt

I'm trying to decode a token I have received from an authorization service. The problem is when I try to decode it I get `InvalidAlgorithmError: the specified alg value is not allowed`.

When you look at the following image below. I can decode the token from the **jwt.io** site and view the payload.

I'm using the [PyJwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/) library. Below you will find my implementation.

**Decoded token in the jwt.io site**

[image]

**Implementation**

```
import jwt 

    encoded = "eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJERVZFTE9QRVIiLCJ1c2VyZnVsbG5hbWUiOiJFcmljIE0gS2FyaW1pIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJlcmljIiwidXNlcmlkIjoiMjkiLCJleHAiOjE1NzM0ODE0MzIsImlzcyI6IkVyaWMiLCJhdWQiOiJSZWFkZXJzIn0.tTQckIZGYNHE667NXrxT4YwT4DNZ01u3P3b3IMFyWR4"

    key = "somekeyrequiredtodecode"

    decoded = jwt.decode(encoded,key, algorithms=['HS256'])
```

## Full StackTrace

```
~/Desktop/APIs/ncc-api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py in decode(self, jwt, key, verify, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
    154         elif verify_signature:
    155             self._verify_signature(payload, signing_input, header, signature,
--> 156                                    key, algorithms)
    157 
    158         return payload

~/Desktop/APIs/ncc-api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py in _verify_signature(self, payload, signing_input, header, signature, key, algorithms)
    214 
    215         if algorithms is not None and alg not in algorithms:
--> 216             raise InvalidAlgorithmError('The specified alg value is not allowed')
    217 
    218         try:

InvalidAlgorithmError: The specified alg value is not allowed

In [7]: v = jwt.decode(key, s, algorithms=['HS256'])                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidAlgorithmError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a9465dfcaa4b> in <module>
----> 1 v = jwt.decode(key, s, algorithms=['HS256'])

~/Desktop/APIs/ncc-api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py in decode(self, jwt, key, verify, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
     90 
     91         decoded = super(PyJWT, self).decode(
---> 92             jwt, key=key, algorithms=algorithms, options=options, **kwargs
     93         )
     94 

~/Desktop/APIs/ncc-api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py in decode(self, jwt, key, verify, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
    154         elif verify_signature:
    155             self._verify_signature(payload, signing_input, header, signature,
--> 156                                    key, algorithms)
    157 
    158         return payload

~/Desktop/APIs/ncc-api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py in _verify_signature(self, payload, signing_input, header, signature, key, algorithms)
    214 
    215         if algorithms is not None and alg not in algorithms:
--> 216             raise InvalidAlgorithmError('The specified alg value is not allowed')
    217 
    218         try:
InvalidAlgorithmError: The specified alg value is not allowed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm specified in the Header is not a valid one for the library. You need to encode the JWT with `{ "alg": "HS256"}` if you want to decode with these.

You can check the supported algorithms:

```py
from jwt.algorithms import get_default_algorithms

get_default_algorithms()
```

Comment: None of the algorithms that are listed by the `get_default_algorithms()` function helps me out. I still get the same error. In my case the token that I receive is from AWS Cognito. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

In some (not recommended) cases you don't need to validate the signature.
If this is your case, use:

```
jwt.decode(encoded_str, options={"verify_signature": False})
```

https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#reading-the-claimset-without-validation

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. This is extremely insecure. Please stop upvoting this.