# PyJWT decoding showing error "The specified alg value is not allowed" for 'RS512' even if it is listed in supported algorithms

Tags: python, jwt, python-cryptography, pyjwt

I'm calling the decode function like that:

```
payload = jwt.decode(token,
                     cert['key'],
                     algorithms=['RS512'],
                     audience=aud,
                     leeway=0,
               
                     )
```

The error I m having:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 292, in _verify_signature
raise InvalidAlgorithmError("The specified alg value is not allowed")

jwt.exceptions.InvalidAlgorithmError: The specified alg value is not allowed
```

The `crypto` extra is installed via `poetry` in `pyproject.toml`:

```
 PyJWT =  {version = "^2.5.0", extras = ["crypto"]}
 cryptography = "^38.0.2"
```

The listing of supported algorithms listed the algorithm "RS512":

```
get_default_algorithms().keys()
```

giving

```
(['none', 'HS256', 'HS384', 'HS512', 'RS256', 'RS384', 'RS512', 'ES256', 'ES256K', 'ES384', 'ES521', 'ES512', 'PS256', 'PS384', 'PS512', 'EdDSA']
```

Anyone who has this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the error can have different causes, I suggest checking the error line message **_verify_signature** in which it indicates that the signature can not be verified as indicated in the [documentation](https://Because%20the%20error%20can%20have%20different%20causes,%20I%20suggest%20checking%20the%20error%20line%20in%20which%20it%20indicates%20that%20the%20signature%20must%20be%20validated%20as%20indicated%20in%20the%20documentation%20and%20in%20this%20post) and in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801564/fix-invalidalgorithmerror-the-specified-alg-value-is-not-allowed-while-trying)

```py
>>> jwt.decode(encoded, options={"verify_signature": False})
{'some': 'payload'}
```

...

```py
>>> jwt.get_unverified_header(encoded)
{'alg': 'RS512'}
```

Comment: you are right : `unverified : {'alg': 'HS256', 'typ': 'JWT'}`, seems the token is generated by different cert and different algo

Comment: I can also notice that in the `get_unverified_header` section other key values like `"typ"` and `"kid"` are defined but I haven't been able to identify the proper parameters for **RS512**, but if you know the specifications for that specific algorithm you could better improvise your program, I would recommend checking [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature algorithm using SHA-512 hash algorithm](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/algorithms.html#digital-signature-algorithms)

Comment: the token is invalid, I used a correct token generated by same certificate and it is working fine, thank you for  the answer and pointing into `jwt.get_unverified_header(encoded)`